# Block is not inline

Tags: css, css-float, display

I've been looking at the styles for a couple of hours yet and I'm not seeing the solution. A Wordpress style is being integrated into a phpBB style, probably not a good idea due to naming conflicts. The Last Post information for a forum is sitting on another line for reasons I don't understand.

http://www.vinyl-replacement-windows.com/forum/index.php

Normally it would sit on the right of the Post column, as shown here:

https://www.phpbb.com/customise/db/style/allan_style_subsilver/demo/3.2

The .lastpost class is display:block and float:left so it should work. Where is the conflict?

Comment: width exceeded by all the float element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the width. if it exceeds parent container elements stack. try decreasing width of .lastpost

Comment: Thanks. Reducing it made it fit but I think there is likely a larger issue, perhaps the font size is too big.

Comment: Reducing the size of `ul.topiclist dt` to `90%` also works.